# How can I automate Windows Store updates?

Tags: windows-10, automation, windows-store

I am looking for a way to automatically download and apply updates for windows store apps. The closest thing I have been able to find is this:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5ac7daa9-54e6-43c0-9746-293dcb8ef2ec/how-to-force-update-of-windows-store-apps-without-launching-the-store-app?forum=win10itprosetup

One answer in that link seems to apply to the Deployment Toolkit, which I am not using.

The other mentions a scheduled task, but when I find and run that task it does not perform the updates (it seems to run indefinitely).

I want to run a program (preferably in C# but command line or powershell is fine) that downloads and applies Windows Store App updates. How can I do this?

Comment: Just checking: are you looking for something different than the Store's built-in feature to automatically update Store apps?

Comment: @CBHacking Yes. I am looking to preconfigure a large group of systems for testing. Those systems do not automatically update quickly or reliably on their own - some will update, some will not unless I manually check for updates 5+ times, etc. I need a surefire way to just run a script and guarantee that after it completes the WS apps will be up to date.